# How to sample a signal using Golomb Ruler?

Tags: matlab, plot, signals, sampling

I'm trying to sample a multi-sine signal by Golomb Ruler of length 151, how can I achieve this ?

Below is the signal plot for a sine wave sampled by Golomb Ruler of length 151.
[image]

Amplitude spectrum of the above samples (visible peak at the
expected frequency 24Hz above the “under-sampling” noise)
[image]

```
clear all
close all
clc

%%
Fs = 1000;                    % Sampling Freq.
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sampling period
L = 1024;                     % Length of signal
t = 2*(0:L-1)*T;            % Time vector

x = 0;                        % Signal intial value
y = 0;                        % Signal intial value
F = 24;                       % Signal Freq.

seq = [0 4 20 30 57 59 62 76 100 111 123 136 144 145 151]; %Golomb Seq. ??

% x = cos(2*pi*F*seq);

for i01=1:length(seq)
    for u = 0:seq(i01)
    x = x + cos(2*pi*F*u+pi/2);
    end
end

figure
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(seq,x)
title('Original signal')
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Are you asking how to reproduce the included figures?

Comment: yes,
I am trying to generate a sine wave signal and sample it using the Golomb Ruler, which should give me the above figures.